# Django error: [Errno 60] Operation timed out

Tags: django

I know the title is a little ambiguous and I'd only ever ask here if it wasn't a last resort - but I am stuck. I've pulled down a Django project from my work repo that is rather ancient (we're talking 1.13), and I've been tasked with bringing it into 1.9. Okay, fair enough.

I've loaded the database from a MySQL dump and faked the migrations just fine. However, when I run the server, I get hit with this:

```
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 256, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 316, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 291, in _get_socket
    return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 575, in create_connection
    raise err
error: [Errno 60] Operation timed out
```

At first, I had no idea what was going on here, but from the look of it, SMTP is throwing this exception - probably due to the mailing server not being accessible. Any how, I can't even get print statements to show up in `settings.py`, and so have no idea where to even start to trace this problem through.

Any guidance would be lovely.

EDIT: Here is the new error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 85, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/Users/krisvukasinovic/.virtualenvs/give2gether/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 63, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/krisvukasinovic/.virtualenvs/give2gether/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 177, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/Users/krisvukasinovic/.virtualenvs/give2gether/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 230, in get_response
    response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
  File "/Users/krisvukasinovic/.virtualenvs/give2gether/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 284, in handle_uncaught_exception
    'request': request
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1191, in error
    self._log(ERROR, msg, args, **kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1284, in _log
    self.handle(record)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1294, in handle
    self.callHandlers(record)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1334, in callHandlers
    hdlr.handle(record)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 757, in handle
    self.emit(record)
  File "/Users/krisvukasinovic/.virtualenvs/give2gether/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/log.py", line 117, in emit
    self.send_mail(subject, message, fail_silently=True, html_message=html_message)
  File "/Users/krisvukasinovic/.virtualenvs/give2gether/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/log.py", line 120, in send_mail
    mail.mail_admins(subject, message, *args, connection=self.connection(), **kwargs)
  File "/Users/krisvukasinovic/.virtualenvs/give2gether/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py", line 97, in mail_admins
    mail.send(fail_silently=fail_silently)
  File "/Users/krisvukasinovic/.virtualenvs/give2gether/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 292, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "/Users/krisvukasinovic/.virtualenvs/give2gether/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 100, in send_messages
    new_conn_created = self.open()
  File "/Users/krisvukasinovic/.virtualenvs/give2gether/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 58, in open
    self.connection = connection_class(self.host, self.port, **connection_params)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 256, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 316, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 291, in _get_socket
    return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 575, in create_connection
    raise err
error: [Errno 61] Connection refused
```

Comment: Does the error disappear if you put the `ADMINS` and `SERVER_EMAIL` settings inside an `if not DEBUG`? (This isn't a solution)

Comment: @Sayse hm. it would run if I do that, as it throws a `SERVER_EMAIL not defined` error

Comment: @Sayse if I put all of the email params and ADMINS in that `if not`, the error changes to an `error: [Errno 61] Connection refused`

Comment: Kris, thats what I thought would be the problem, you're actually getting a different error but the fact that its trying to email to tell you about that is hiding it, would you mind adding that error to your question? (Looks to be a db connection failure perhaps?)

Comment: @Sayse sure! will do. Perhaps... is there anyway I could test that? MySQL is running.

Comment: Are you using the `AdminEmailHandler` for your logging? it still appears to be trying to send an email

Comment: You might want to disable that for the time being too, either switch to a ConsoleHandler as per [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/logging/#examples) or just stick it in the if not DEBUG again (again these aren't solutions)

Comment: @Sayse alright, well I got a regular error now. Hopefully I can do some tracing. Thanks so much for the guidance!

Comment: No worries! I've added an answer with the solution I was avoiding mentioning (only because it would have taken longer to set up than the simple `if not DEBUG`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you know, the error you were getting is because your logger was set up to send emails whenever you received an error. The problem being that your development environment doesn't have access to the mail server that this logger relies on.

What happens is django then raises this new error and the actual error gets hidden away.

The actual solution to this is to create a separate `settings.py` file for development, that way you don't need to worry about the mail server not being there, nor (I expect) would you really care.

When running `runserver` you can then specify this settings file with

```
 runserver --settings=mysettings
```

For completeness, heres a very simple development settings.py file

```
from myapp.settings import *

print 'DEV'
DEBUG = True
# INSTALLED_APPS += ['debug_toolbar']
# MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES += ['debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware']
```

Comment: I really appreciate the help! I'll give that a go. I just have one question. Is there a reason why I can't see any print statements, even at the start of the settings file? I tried to trace the error that way but couldn't.

Comment: @Kris - I have no idea, its hard to say what the issue would be, there isn't any problem with using prints in the settings.py file, I've included one in my edit that shows a simple example of a dev settings file you could use, it prints out `DEV` for me to the console

Comment: you rock! Thank you so very much for seeing this error through. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Kris - No worries! hope it helped and you found the actual error!