# Django - EmailMessage working in shell but dont working in view with same data

Tags: django, django-email

I want to send mail after form valid. So i using EmailMessage class .

My code like this.

```py
EmailMessage(subject='ddd', body='ff2', from_email='test@gmail.com', to=['test@gmail.com'], reply_to=['test@gmail.com'], headers={}).send()
```

This code work very well in django shell. But not work when i use to in django views.

```py
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'test@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = password_create_with_google_app
EMAIL_PORT = 587
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
```

Comment: What error does it provide when you call it from views?

Comment: error (60) operation timed out

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35450763/django-error-errno-60-operation-timed-out

Comment: did not work for me